# Making a screen icon by Mathematica

Tags: graphics, image

Is it possible to make within Mathematica an image file to be used as a screen icon? Could you kindly give an example?

Comment: Can you give more details? On Ubuntu I can use all kind of images for app-icons. Therefore, the answer would be *yes, just export e.g. a png-image* but I think your question goes in another direction.

Comment: And, before exporting to png you can scale the image using `ImageResize`. For a 128x128 pixels icon: `ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], {128, 128}]`.

Comment: Thank you. That is more or less what I wanted to do. However, after I do that (for example with Lena as proposed) the PC does not recognize it as an icon file. For instance, I cannot use it for changing an icon of a shortcut.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Might be that you need a specific file format (.ico, .icns,...)?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, if you are on Windows and if you mean the Windows-typic ICO files that VLC mentioned, than it seems you have to use another tool. Although Mathematica [can import](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/ICO.html) those files, it cannot export them.

Comment: So, as much as I understand you, it is impossible to make it completely within Mathematica. I have to go to another soft at some step, have I? Can you give a tip, which soft would make it most easy?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch You might use one of the tools that are available [online](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=create+ico+file).

Comment: I thank VLC and halirutan for advises. I think with these advises my question is answered.

Comment: Version 9 will add support for .ICO export and .ICNS import/export.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Since, with others help, you've found the answer, I encourage you to answer this question so it will be helpful for future visitors.

Comment: Has anyone had any news to create icon in Mathematica?

Answer (score 3):

Here in response to the request of Kuba I give the answer to my own question. I an not the author to this answer, and I have to apologize, since I did not record, who gave this answer, and where it has been given. Anyway, here it is.

The answer would be yes, just export e.g. a png-image. And, before exporting to png you can scale the image using `ImageResize`. For a 128x128 pixels icon:

```
imLena = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], {128, 128}]
```

You further need a specific file format (.ico, .icns,...). If you are on Windows and if you mean the Windows-typic ICO files, than it seems you have to use another tool. Although *Mathematica* can import those files, it cannot export them. You might use one of the tools that are available online: http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=create+ico+file.

Among these references there is a nice tool converting png files into ico files. Its address is:
http://www.convertico.com/ . 
The operation is as follows:

Step 1: Make an image needed to be transformed into ico and resize it as it is shown above.

Step 2: Export it as a png file.

Step 3: Open the "convertico" page http://www.convertico.com/ , at the text field "Select File From Your Computer" click the button "Browse" and navigate to the png file in question. Click the button "Go".

Step 4: Click the rose field with the white arrow. In the dialog that will appear choose "Save file". Bring the saved ico file into the directory for icons. The current directory on this machine is C://Windows/Custom icons.

Step 5: Go to the icon to be replaced/Properties/Customize/Change icon and in the dialog that will appear browse to the desired ico file

Now my estimate of this procedure. I works perfectly, enabling one to make really nice icons just out of the collection of Google pictures or from the images obtained within Mma. Like this one, for instance, [image].

I have a problem with the system, however, that is PC/XP. The icon are shown sometimes, and sometimes they are not. Sometimes they are shown from the moment when my computer is just switched on (as it is expected from any descent icon), and sometimes after computer has already worked several hours. Probably, I put them into a wrong location. I do not know.

Comment: Has anyone had any news to create icon in Mathematica?