# How to create .ico file in Mathematica?

Tags: export, image, files-and-directories

How to create .ico file in Mathematica?  I mean the [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) images used for web sites.  Directly using `Export["file.ico", <some graphical expression>]` does not seem to work.

Comment: If you have imagemagic installed on mac or linux(windows I believe supports this also) I would do `convert favicon.ico favicon.png` Surely you could easily couple this with an png export.

Comment: If this is a one time thing I agree with Liam, and the is awash with [alternative](http://favicon-generator.org/) solutions.

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* are you on, and what OS? I'm guessing version 8, right?

Comment: @Problemaniak Have a look also here: ´http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/making-a-screen-icon-by-mathematica´

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exporting `.ico` from *Mathematica* works fine in version 9.0.1. On Mac, the built-in function `sips` tells me that it only supports image sizes that are a power of 2. So you could try to create the desired file using this:

```
Export["img.ico", img, ImageSize -> {256, 256}]
```

where `img` is the image to be exported. However, in version 9.0.1 I'm able to export arbitrarily sized images to `.ico` as well.

Comment: As for the ImageSize, the documentation says:"ICO supports a maximum of 256*256 pixels images. Export will scale down Image and Graphics larger than 256 pixels to fit."

Comment: So, `ImageSize -> {256, 256}` in Jens' program above is not necessary, right?

Comment: I just did an experiment which seems to confirm that `ImageSize -> {256, 256}` is not necessary, at least for Mathematica 9.0.1 in Mac.

Comment: @Problemaniac It's not necessary, but I threw it in as a guess because I don't know for sure why the OP is having trouble. Maybe the answer boils down to: upgrade to version 9.0.1.